# Change SupportActionBar from inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I just googled for "**s**etsupportactionbar fragment", but all I found was "**g**etsupportactionbar from fragment". Is that similar to each other, or is there something special?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is similar, **but** you have to keep in mind that you have to place `setSupportActionBar()` in `onCreateView` if you want to use elements of fragments layout-file:

```
..
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    ..
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        return view;
    }
    ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not use `setSupportActionBar()` in fragment. because every time you add this fragment on activity a new instance of toolbar is created. so every time a new Toolbar is showing in screen. so it is not a good approach.

Comment: I know. For my case it was important, to replace it with another toolbar.

Comment: I've a NavigationDrawer+Toolbar. If a special item in that drawer is called the toolbar will be hidden and a new toolbar set as supportactionbar. I am using [ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) for this.

Comment: what do you mean by new toolbar. i already said that for one activity there is only one instance of toolbar

Comment: Could we shift to a private chat?